# Label don't update ui on runtime

Tags: c#, label

I try to update the `forecolor` and `text` of a label in run time by `invoke`, The `text` changes but the `forecolor` does'nt. What could it be?

Code:

```
this.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    lbl.Text="Home";
    lbl.ForeColor=Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
The label was of [Metro Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/) control, and I was needed to define `lbl.UseCustomForeColor=True`